# Shared Editor Templates based on property names?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In an ASP.net MVC 4 web application, I have 5 model classes that all have the same property, say `string ManufacturerName`. I want to present a dropdown list of Manufacturers from the database(list data passed from controller to view using `ViewBag`) in the create/edit templates of these models. It is possible to do it but I am repeating the dropdown code in all the 5 Editor Templates

```
@Html.DropDownList("ManufacturerName", new SelectList(ViewBag.ManufacturerList))
```

I was hoping there is some way to just write the above dropdown code once in an Editor Template called "Manufacturer.cshtml" as a partial view and be able to call it from the model templates like so

```
@Html.EditorForModel(model => model.ManufacturerName)
```

I know above line would normally call an editor template for `string` since that's the type of `ManufacturerName` but is there a way to change it to match the property name instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new EditorTemplate in `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Manufacturer.cshtml` with:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ManufacturerName", new SelectList(ViewBag.ManufacturerList))
```

Then decorate the property in your ViewModel with `[UIHint]`:

```
[UIHint("Manufacturer")]
public string ManufacturerName { get; set; }
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to modify your ViewModel, you can pass a `templateName` argument to the `EditorFor()` method:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Manufacturer, "Manufacturer")
```

The problem with the last approach is that the appropriate template will not be used if editor is rendered using `@Html.EditorForModel()`.

Comment: That's fine. I don't care whether I use EditorFor or EditorForModel or a partial view.

Comment: Will the ViewBag be passed from the calling view to the editor template?

Comment: The `ViewBag` is available through the lifetime of your `ViewContext`. be it a Layout, Partial, EditorTemplate or regular View. you should be ok then.

Comment: I imagine @Html.EditorFor can't detect the editor template called Manufacturer without explicitly mentioning the name?

Comment: @sgag, no. but, you can easily create your own extension method (`@Html.MyEditorFor()` for example) that will call `@Html.EditorFor` with the property name parameter for you. you can also force the property name into the `ModelMetaData` in the `ViewContext` but that's a bit harder.

Answer (score 1):

Create a ViewModel that holds onto the SelectList and the property you wish to bind to:

```
public class ManufacturerListViewModel
{
   public SelectList ManufacturerList { get; set; }
   public string ManufacturerName { get; set; }
}
```

Then the Editor Template:

```
@model ManufacturerListModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ManufacturerName, Model.ManufacturerList)
```

Then call it in your Views:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Manufacturer)
```

Comment: I wouldn't prefer to change the model since I would like any other controller action to be able to use the view without having to attach this list to it anytime the view is used.

Comment: The list inclusion should happen in the background without any supervision since it's basically a static list. Is there an ajax way to do this?